# Is it possible to access to java.util.LinkedList node directly?

Tags: java, linked-list

Is it possible to access to `java.util.LinkedList` node directly, and manually swap two nodes by change next and prev links?

Comment: The official answer is no. You can probably do it through reflection but you shouldn't. What you can possibly do is use a `ListIterator`. That allows traversing both ways, has internal links to the nodes, and has the option to `set` the value.

Comment: The `Node` class inside `LinkedList` is `private`.  So you really can't mess with it.  Although there are ways to use Reflection to make `private` things a little less `private`, you really shouldn't be doing that.  And even if you could freely assign `next` and `prev`, there are many edge cases in the required logic, so this would be insanely complicated.

Comment: This is just a bad idea. Then you have two ways in which node position can change, and this becomes a multi-threading safety nightmare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The node is not publicly accessible, and it's an implementation detail that may change or even disappear in a given Java runtime.

Yes. With sufficient effort and ongoing care, you can use reflection to manipulate the normally inaccessible innards of a particular implementation.

I suspect this might be an XY problem, and if you described your goal, it might be that a different collection would work better.

---

For an LRU cache, you could use [`LinkedHashMap`,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#LinkedHashMap-int-float-boolean-) with the access-order flag set.